# Bad request 400 error with slack notification when there is a larger text in txt file in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, slack, slack-block-kit

I have the txt file with the following content and I am creating it runtime in bitbucket pipeline.

```
+---------------+---------------+
| Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
+---------------+---------------+
|           0.0 |         0.125 |
|          50.0 |         0.292 |
|          90.0 |         1.045 |
|          95.0 |         2.086 |
|          99.0 |        10.048 |
|          99.9 |        10.048 |
|         100.0 |        10.048 |
+---------------+---------------+
+-----------------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| label                       | status |    succ | avg_rt | error |
+-----------------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| Category List               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.461 |       |
| Collections List            |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.204 |       |
| Create Collection           |   OK   | 100.00% |  1.112 |       |
| Create Collection With CMF  |   OK   | 100.00% |  1.045 |       |
| Create Favorite             |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.125 |       |
| Delete Folder               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.292 |       |
| Delete Image                |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.230 |       |
| Delete Misc Asset           |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.460 |       |
| Delete PDF                  |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.236 |       |
| Delete Template             |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.240 |       |
| Delete Video                |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.158 |       |
| Favorite List               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.862 |       |
| Get Image                   |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.184 |       |
| Get Misc Asset              |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.214 |       |
| Get PDF                     |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.207 |       |
| Get template                |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.204 |       |
| Insert Cat_ID and Get Video |   OK   | 100.00% | 10.049 |       |
| Insert Folder               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.814 |       |
| Insert Template             |   OK   | 100.00% |  1.018 |       |
| Insert and Get Image        |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.767 |       |
| Insert and Get Misc         |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.760 |       |
| Insert and Get PDF          |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.604 |       |
| OAuth                       |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.591 |       |
| Replace Video               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.183 |       |
| Search List 1               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.404 |       |
| Search List 10              |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.264 |       |
| Search List 2               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.191 |       |
| Search List 3               |   OK   | 100.00% |  2.087 |       |
| Search List 4               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.274 |       |
| Search List 5               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.261 |       |
| Search List 6               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.824 |       |
| Search List 7               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.285 |       |
| Search List 8               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.175 |       |
| Search List 9               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.946 |       |
| Update Collection           |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.655 |       |
| Update Favorite             |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.149 |       |
| Update Folder               |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.490 |       |
+-----------------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
```

When I try to print the content from the file using the command below, I get the error:

> -pipe: atlassian/slack-notify:2.0.1
> variables:
> WEBHOOK_URL: $WEBHOOK_URL
> MESSAGE: 'echo $(cat log.txt)'

This is the error:

> ✖ Notification failed. Pipe has finished with an error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/AAAAAAAA/BBBBBBBB/CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

It seems like the error is occurring because of the size of the text. Please can someone help and let me know how can it be fixed and the following text can be displayed in slack channel. Thanks